# What does this error in Sass mean? "Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties."

Tags: css, ruby, sass

This is my code

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

body {
font-family: 'Open Sans';
}

.navigation {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
background: #333;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
z-index: 999;
width: 100%
li {
    display: inline;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    a {
        color: #e1e1e1;
        text-decoration: none;
        a:hover{color: lighten(#e1e1e1, 20%);}
        }
    }
}
```

But whenever I build it and refresh the webpage I get this error:

```
Syntax error: Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties.
        on line 23 of style.scss
```

here is the my css code with line numbers

```
18:     z-index: 999;
19:     width: 100%
20:     li {
21:         display: inline;
22:         padding: 5px 10px;
23:         a {
24:             color: #e1e1e1;
25:             text-decoration: none;
26:             a:hover{color: lighten(#e1e1e1, 20%);}
27:         }
28:     }
```

I guess it's the anchor tag that's creating the problem but I don't understand why. Theoretically it should work.

Comment: I'd try adding the semicolon at the end of line 19 - it looks like the compiler thinks you're trying to use this syntax: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/02/sass-snippets-compact-syntax-for-nested.html

Comment: Also, I think you might want to use `&:hover` on line 26 instead of `a:hover` since it looks like you want to target the same parent - `a` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. It works now. But I don't understand something. Why would it show this error on line 23 instead of line 20?

Comment: Note to close voters:  while this could be construed as a "typographical error", it is not an obvious one:  the trailing semicolon is optional in CSS.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're missing a semicolon:

```
.navigation {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #333;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
  width: 100%;   <=== right here
```

Answer (score 10):

Although this isn't the correct answer for this specific question, others who stumble upon this article because they encounter the same error message ("Illegal nesting: Only properties may be nested beneath properties.") may find the cause to be related to using the `scss_lint` gem. In particular, if you've upgraded from `scss-lint` to `scss_lint`, you may need to add `require: false` to your Gemfile to get things working again.

Reference: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/issues/496

Docs: https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint#installation

Comment: Thanks so much stevo. This saved me :).

Comment: Thanks, saved me from reading/looking for issue on my css w/ 1K+ of lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Like stevo's answer, this doesn't matter for the specific question, but I have another reason why you may see this error: whitespace.

Somehow, I had a single line which was tab indented rather than spaces. This totally confused SASS. If you're seeing this error, take a look at your whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error and none of the options above worked :/
I thought the "require: false" was going to work but it didn't. 
What it worked for me was installing the [linter-scss](https://atom.io/packages/linter-scss-lint) plugin for Atom. After  I installed, I compiled again and it worked. I hope it works for you too guys. 
Regards, Bernardo.

Answer (score 0):

This error can also arise when you use **spaces** in your SASS and the compiler encounters a **tabulation**.

It can easily happen when you copy-paste some code and your editor does not convert those tabs into spaces.