# Strange gulp crashes caused by SASS errors

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp

im currently building a project and using a Gulp as task runner, and gulp-sass as a SASS compilation engine.
The problem is, whenever i commit mistake in my main.scss file, in line other described fragment at the end of file (code below) , everything goes well, gulp handeles sass error as intended, and keeps on funtioning.(example below)

```
[18:14:28] Starting 'sass'...
[18:14:28] Finished 'sass' after 3.25 ms
Error in plugin 'sass'
Message:
    src\sass\main.scss
Error: Invalid CSS after "    margin": expected "}", was ": 0;"
        on line 37 of stdin
>>     margin: 0;
   ----^
```

But when it is a semicolon on line 65 the whole thing just stops working, without any logs, and refuses tu lauch unless i fix it.(example)

```
[18:19:23] Starting 'sass'...
[18:19:23] Finished 'sass' after 3.18 ms

C:\test
```

Any ideas what causing this error? I know that most obvious solution is "noy commiting mistakes in sass", but still, i would like to solve it.

Node version 5.9.1.
OS - Windows 10.
https://bitbucket.org/gentos/strangegulpbehaviour I've also placed a troublesome sass and gulpfile file into a mini project if there will be a need to reproduce an error.
Thanks in advance for your time and help!

This code, placed at the end of any of my main gulp files caused a described behaviour. Removed rest cos of irrelivance.

```
nav{
    position: fixed
    ul{
      li{
      }
    }
}
```

gulpfile.js

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    watch = require('gulp-watch'),
    cleanCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
    browserSync = require("browser-sync"),
    gutil = require('gulp-util'),
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var path = {
    build: { 
        html: 'build/',
        js: 'build/js/',
        css: 'build/css/',
        image: 'build/img/'

    },
    src: { 
        html: 'src/*.html', 
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        sass: 'src/sass/**/*.scss',
        css: 'src/css/**/*.css',
        image: 'src/img/*'
    },
    watch: {
        html: 'src/**/*.html',
        js: 'src/js/**/*.js',
        sass: 'src/sass/*',
        css: 'src/css/**/*.css',
        image: 'src/img/*'
    },
    clean: './build'
};


function handleErrors() {
  var gutil = require('gulp-util');
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  gutil.log(gutil.colors.white.bgRed.underline.bold('Gulp error:'));
  gutil.log(gutil.colors.red(args));

  this.emit('end');
}
gulp.task('html',function(){
    gulp.src(path.src.html)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.html))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));
});

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: [path.build.html]
        }
    });
});



gulp.task('sass',function(){                
  gulp.src('./src/sass/main.scss')
    .pipe(sass({includePaths: ['./src/sass']}).on('error', sass.logError))  
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(cleanCSS({debug: true}, function(details) {
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.originalSize);
            console.log(details.name + ': ' + details.stats.minifiedSize);
        }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css))
    .pipe(reload({stream: true}));

});



gulp.task('watch', function(){
    watch([path.watch.sass], function(event, cb) {
        gulp.start('sass');
    });
});


gulp.task('default', ["sass", "html", "browser-sync" ,"watch"]);
```

Comment: do you already know https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-plumber ?

Comment: I was able to run your repository code fine:

$ gulp sass
[17:19:09] Using gulpfile ~/projects/strangegulpbehaviour/gulpfile.js
[17:19:09] Starting 'sass'...
[17:19:09] Finished 'sass' after 11 ms
main.css: 1409
main.css: 1056

Comment: I don't see an [MCVE] here for the Sass in question.  The provided code would produce an ["Illegal nesting"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977744/what-does-this-error-in-sass-mean-illegal-nesting-only-properties-may-be-nest) error, and the code in the linked repo compiles without error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run this command and reset the universe

```
npm install gulp-sass
```

or trace the error

```
sass --trace --watch input.scss:output.css
```